# Путь к файлу базы данных в JDBC

Tags: база-данных, jdbc, h2

Как указать путь к файлу базы данных относительно проекта, а не относительно компьютера, чтобы не возникло проблем при переносе проекта на другой компьютер или при его сборке?

> connect = DriverManager.getConnection("**jdbc:h2:file://F:\test**", "sa","");

Какой url JDBC нужно указать вместо **jdbc:h2:file://F:\test**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сперва создай БД в папке проекта:

```
public static void main(String args[]) { 
     JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
     ds.setURL("jdbc:h2:file:./test");
     ds.setUser("sa");
     ds.setPassword("");
     try {
         Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

**Ну, или можешь просто перенести файл test.db в корневую папку проекта**
А после используй url:

```
"jdbc:h2:file:./test"
```

Comment: благодарю.опять выручили!

Comment: @Георгий если этот ответ решил вашу проблему, то закройте вопрос, нажмав на зеленую галочку рядом с моим ответом